# rounded image link issue

Tags: html, css

I have used the following image as background image for link.

[image]

If I hover over the image the link display in the edges also. I just want to show the link for exact round image and not for the blank edges. Is there any possibility to do this in css?

[image]

```
css:

.buy_purple a{ background-image:url(../imagesf/buy_purple.png); width:81px; height:57px; background-repeat:no-repeat; float:right; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c9a3c2; text-align:center; padding-top:29px; color:#000;}

Html: 

<div class="buy_purple"><a href="#">BUY</a></div>
```

Comment: It will be great if you show us some `html` `css`

Comment: but we are not able to see the image still because its own your local computer can you make it live...

Comment: The image is used in the post...

Comment: hey sam ru looking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/yY4FzaZr

Answer (score 0):

If you get your image to be square and perfectly centered, you can just use the `border-radius` property, which will affect the effective clickable area as well.

```
a{
    ...
    display: block;

    border-radius: 40px; /* if the height+width are 80px */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tvJMG/

Comment: What's the example all about?

Comment: What do you mean? The example is showing that the code works. If you mouse over the empty areas of the circle that would've been occupied in a square, the link won't be activated.

Comment: I was talking about your jsfiddle link , seems to be blank mate.

Comment: Oh, whoops - you're right. I'll get that fixed up right away.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `map` tag

```
 <img src="test.png" alt="test" usemap="links"/>
 <map name="links">
    <area shape="circle" coords="your image co-ords(centerX,centerY,Radius)" href="your link" />
 </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey are you looking like this :-

http://tinkerbin.com/yY4FzaZr

**HTML**

```
<div class="buy_purple"><a href="#">BUY</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.buy_purple a{ background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC3xc.png); width:81px; height:57px; background-repeat:no-repeat; float:right; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c9a3c2; text-align:center; padding-top:29px; color:#000;}
.buy_purple a:hover {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Jia.jpg) no-repeat 1px -5px;
}
```

or your are looking in **pure css**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using pure css

Here the html

```
<div>
<a href="/"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg"></a>
</div>
```

Here the css

```
img {
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 169px 169px 169px 169px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
a {
height: 0px;
}
```

Here the demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BthKg/1/)