# Pointer over a circular icon

Tags: html, css

I have some circular icons with border in my website, but when I hover the mouse over the icon, I can see the pointer (and get into the link) from outside the icon.
I've tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302538/rounded-image-link-issue), but it didn't help. Does anybody have a suggestion?

HTML code:

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="margin-icons">
  <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social mx-1" target="_blank" href="mailto:example@example.com">
    <i class="far fa-envelope" style="color: black;
             width: 50px; height: 50px;
             border: 2px solid black;
             border-radius: 50%;
             padding: 6px;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="margin-icons">
  <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social mx-1" target="_blank">
    <i class="far fa-envelope" style="color: black;
             width: 50px; height: 50px;
             border: 2px solid black;
             border-radius: 50%;
             padding: 6px;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

So you don't want the pointer to come then just remove href in the 'a' tag.
But Why do you the three icons?

Comment: But if I'll remove it, it won't lead to mail or anything else. I want the pointer to be seen only inside the circular border.

Comment: and why are there three buttons?